# Prove that if h is an integrable function, then $ \lim_{c \to 0}$ of the integral over the real line of $|h(x)-h(x+c)| = 0$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Prove that if h is an integrable function, then the $ \lim_{c \to 0}$ of the integral over the real line of $|h(x)-h(x+c)| = 0$

For this problem would I just say that $h(x)= h(x+c)$ almost everywhere for $c>$ some $N$?

Comment: Start with the indicator function of an interval. In this case you can work out $$ \int_{\mathbb R} |h(x+c) -h(x)| \, dx$$ exactly. Show that limit is zero, and then go about the usual limiting process to extend to integrable functions $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good way to prove this is to prove it first for continuous, compactly suported functions (which are uniformly continuous) and then to use the density of such functions in $L^1$.